# Common-practice in dealing with high-load tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, transactions, database, high-load

I have a table in MySQL 5 (InnoDB) that is used as a daemon Processing Queue, thus it is being accessed *very* often. It is typical to have around 250 000 records inserted per day. When I select records to be processed, they are read using a FOR UPDATE query to eliminate race conditions (everything is Transaction Based).

Now I am developing a "queue archive" and I have stumbled into a serious dead-lock problem. I need to delete "executed" records from the table as they are being processed (live), yet the table dead-locks every once in a while if I do so (two-three times per day at).

I though of moving towards delayed deletion (once per day at low load times) but this will not eliminate the problem only make it less obvious.

Is there a common-practice in dealing with high-load tables in MySQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`InnoDB` locks all rows it examines, not only those requested.

See [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1306896/deadlocks-on-mysql-deleting-rows) for more details.

You need to create an index that would exactly match your search condition to get rid of unnecessary locks, and make sure it is used.

Unfortunately, `DML` queries in `MySQL` do not accept hints.

Comment: Hm, interesting. What if I use "SELECT id FROM table WHERE foo = bar LIMIT 1 FOR UPDATE" -- will this ensure that only one row is locked?

Comment: No. If a full table scan be be chosen by the optimizer, it will lock all rows examined before the engine finds the first row matching the criteria.